# Ajax filter column datatable

Tags: ajax, datatable

I'd want to display result by column dropdown filter. But after choose table doesn't update result.
My main goal is filter by "Компания" column and that selector must be on top of the table.
`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var exampleDataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    colReorder: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ],
    language: {
      buttons: {
                  colvis: 'Отображение столбцов'
                },
                "processing": "Подождите...",
                "search": "Поиск:",
                "lengthMenu": " _MENU_ ",
                "info": "Показано с _START_ до _END_ записей из _TOTAL_",
                "infoEmpty": "Записи с 0 до 0 из 0 записей",
                "infoFiltered": "(отфильтровано из _MAX_ записей)",
                "infoPostFix": "",
                "loadingRecords": "Загрузка записей...",
                "zeroRecords": "Записи отсутствуют.",
                "emptyTable": "В таблице отсутствуют данные",
                "paginate": {
                "first": "Первая",
                "previous": "<",
                "next": ">",
                "last": "Последняя"
                },
                "aria": {
                "sortAscending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по возрастанию",
                "sortDescending": ": активировать для сортировки столбца по убыванию"
                }
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "aLengthMenu": [[ 3, 10, 20, 50, 100 ,-1],[ 3, 10,20,50,100,"все"]],
    stateSave: true,
    "fnCreatedRow": function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
      $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);
    },
    'serverSide': 'true',
    'processing': 'true',
    'paging': 'true',
    'order': [],
    'ajax': {
      'url': 'fetch_data.php',
      'type': 'post',
      'data': {
        from_attr_1_l: from_attr_1_l,
        from_attr_2_l: from_attr_2_l
      },
    },
initComplete: function () {
  this.api().columns().every(function () {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
      .on('change', function () {
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
          $(this).val()
        );

        column
          .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
          .draw();
      });

    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
      select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
    });
  });
}  }); });
```

`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <table id="example" class="table">
          <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Номер</th>
            <th>ФИО</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>Срок</th>
            <th>Кол-во мест</th>
            <th>Метка</th>
            <th>ИНН</th>
            <th>Телефон</th>
            <th>КПП</th>
            <th>Компания</th>
            <th>Адрес</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Ответственный</th>
            <th>Партнер</th>
            <th>К. телефон</th>
            <th>К. email</th>
            <th></th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
          <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
            <th>Номер</th>
            <th>ФИО</th>
            <th>Дата</th>
            <th>Срок</th>
            <th>Кол-во мест</th>
            <th>Метка</th>
            <th>ИНН</th>
            <th>Телефон</th>
            <th>КПП</th>
            <th>Компания</th>
            <th>Адрес</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Ответственный</th>
            <th>Партнер</th>
            <th>К. телефон</th>
            <th>К. email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

I used different solutions also from https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html and https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/73081/select-dropdown-list-filter but didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "on top of the table" - but take a look at this [additional example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html), which shows how to place your filters in the table header.

Comment: @andrewJames Sorry i've edited my links. Thank you for that example